# GA Event tracking from Salesforce always returns USA as location

Tags: google-analytics, instance

I have created an apex class that sends a POST request to Google with the standard event tracking info eg eventCategory, eventLabel etc. and I use a trigger to initiate the call to track INSERTS and UPDATES to certain objects.

The events are tracked in GA as expected but Google seems to record all my events as coming from USA. Does anyone know why this is?

My best guess is since I'm initiating the call to GA from an Apex class (server side), the code is being executed from a US server even though my instance is on an EU server. Sending a test event from javascript (i.e. client side instead of server side) sets the location correctly.

Comment: Hey Sarina, could you please share a snippet of the code? Especially how you made the connections between the 2 platforms

Answer (score 0):

as force.com is a Platform as a Service (PaaS) so it is located at some server in a cloud. To check where physicaly this server is located you can go to

**Setup -> Administer -> Company Profile -> Company Information**

and check field **Instance**. Based on the value of this field you could know where server is located according to this [article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000257307&language=en_US&type=1).

For example, **NA3**    is Dallas USA / Phoenix, USA

Comment: Thanks for responding. I am on an EU server but i don't think that's the problem. I'm also tracking PageViews on GA and they report the right user location. It's only events that are always recorded as coming from US.

Comment: @SarinaSalim what is an insatnce of your production environment?

Comment: EU14. I've added more info in my original post with a best guess as to the cause. Does it sound probable to you?